# Create Print and delete file C#

Tags: c#, file, printing, process

I have a problem printing a file, I am trying to create a file, print it and them delete it.. here is my code in C#

```
 try
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

                File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

                this.debug(adobePath);
                this.debug(path);
                var isLocked = true;

                /*while (isLocked)
                {
                    try{
                        File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                        isLocked = false;
                        this.debug("FILE IS FREED");
                    }
                    catch(Exception)
                    {
                        this.debug("SLEEP");
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                }*/

                    Process process = new Process();

                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = adobePath;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/t {0} \"{1}\"", path, printerName);
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    // Stops here without printing the file
                    process.Start();

                    process.WaitForExit();

                    if (!process.HasExited)
                    {
                        process.WaitForInputIdle();
                        process.CloseMainWindow();
                        process.Kill();
                    }

                    this.debug("FINISH");
            }
         catch (Exception ex) 
        {
             this.debug(ex.Message);
         }
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }
```

So the problem is that I cannot print the file..
When I try this code without the two first lines (which create the file), so basically I try this code with an existing file, it works and I get the file printed out. 
I am thinking that the problem might come from the **WriteAllBytes()** but it creates the file and write into it and then close it, so the file is not locked anymore.. So I am not sure from where comes the problem! 
Any ideas?

Comment: you seem to have skipped explaining the problem portion.. what isnt working?

Comment: I cannot print the file, and I get no exceptions..

Comment: When I try with an existing file (without creating it) the code works. but when I create the file with the WriteAllBytes() the code fails..

Comment: Have you got any antivirus installed? It can be that anvivirus software or something else blocks file after creating to check it on virus.

Comment: I dont think so  because when I test with a the same file that I created with WriteAllBytes (with the File.Delete() commented, so that I get the file) in a previous execution , and in the second execution I provide directly the path of that file to the printing process, but it doesnt work..

Comment: So to say if something was blocking the file , it wouldn't work in the two cases.